# How to display good morning when the current timeperiod is morning in node js?

Tags: node.js

When the user enters the port the node js should display good morning or good noon or good night.

Comment: Is this an assignment?

Comment: And where are you stuck?  Are you asking how to determine the current time?  How to compare a date/time with known values?  How to output a string?  Something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const date = new Date().getHours()
date < 12 ? 'Good Morning' : date < 18 ? 'Good Afternoon' : 'Good Night'
```